# how can i know and display how many users are within a certain radius on google maps ?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know how can I use a place's location to calculate how many app users are within a certain radius ( for example, how many app users are within a 30 meters radius from a specified starbucks ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but You can Try using below solution:

Get all app user's current `latitude` and `longitude`, and take particular location `latitude` and `longitude` (i.e. starbucks in your case) and calculate distance between that particular location and app user location.

Comment: you completely changed the equation, variables, etc here